# PouchDB.sync() fires 'complete' but PouchDB.replicate.from() with same options only fires 'paused' - why?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

No `complete` event is fired when replicating using `local.replicate.from(remote)`, only `paused`. `{ live: false }` is being specified.

According to the docs when `live` is set to `false` I should be getting a `complete` event. I don't see anything I recognise as errors in my CouchDB server log.

I'm using `pouch-browser` 6.4.3

Local PouchDB options:

```
{
    size: '1000',
    adapter: 'idb',
    auto_compaction: true,
    revs_limit: 1
}
```

'pull' code:

```
local.replicate.from(remote, {
      live: false,
      batch_size: 50,
      batches_limit: 2,
      timeout: 5000,
    })
      .on('change', this.onChange.bind(this))
      .on('paused', this.onPause.bind(this))
      .on('active', this.onActive.bind(this))
      .on('denied', this.onDenied.bind(this))
      .on('complete', this.onComplete.bind(this))
      .on('error', this.onError.bind(this))
      .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
```

This pulls down all the remote records just fine, just no `complete` event, only `paused`. As if the `live: true` is specified.

Here is my sync, code - this always fires a `complete` event. The instance of PouchDB in the `remote` variable is a CouchDB server configured to use proxy authentication - this auth appears to be working just fine.

Two-way replication code:

```
local.sync(remote, {
      live: false,
      batch_size: 50,
      batches_limit: 2,
      timeout: 5000,
    })
      .on('change', this.onChange.bind(this))
      .on('paused', this.onPause.bind(this))
      .on('active', this.onActive.bind(this))
      .on('denied', this.onDenied.bind(this))
      .on('complete', this.onComplete.bind(this))
      .on('error', this.onError.bind(this))
      .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
```

The sync() method always fires a `complete` event as I'd expect with `live: false`. `local.replicate.from()` never does.

Any ideas why I'm not getting a `complete` event in both cases?